# Is there a way to open a link from a PDF file (using laravel snappy) in a new window?

Tags: php, html, laravel, hyperlink

I have a PDF file that's opened to the user's browser on button click, and inside this file I have an anchor tag with an href to a link to an auctions website. I tried adding target="_blank" to the anchor tag but that hasn't worked unfortunately. Is there something I am missing or something I should do?

This is a small chunk of the code where I am using it.
`<p><a href="{{$lot_details->lot_url}}" target="_blank">{{$lot_details->lot_number}}</a></p>`

Comment: What happens exactly when you click the link, then? `target="_blank"` will always cause a new tab/window to be opened in the browser.

Comment: it opens the link, but not in a new tab.

Comment: Not reproducible: https://jsfiddle.net/p5z23y8h/ . Or do you mean it just downloads the file instead of displaying it a new tab? Not all browsers can display documents inline, sometimes they get downloaded.